# displaying image in an image control

Tags: asp.net, sql

I need to retrieve the data information from a database and bind the image to an image control not a datagrid or gridview or datalist.

here the code i m using it not working

```
con.Open()
Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM registration where UserName = @ username", con)
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session("UserName").ToString())
imgUser.ImageUrl = "UserPics/(image1);
con.close()
```

and

```
<asp:Image ID="imgUser" runat="server" Width="340px" Height="150px" ImageUrl="UserPics/<%# Databinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "imagel")  %>.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile. The `;` would have thrown an compilation error on Vb.NET

Comment: no that is just typing mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ username` should not have a space =>
- `"SELECT * FROM registration where UserName = @username",`

`;` should be a `"` =>
- `imgUser.ImageUrl = "UserPics/(image1)"`

Though I'm not sure what that line actually achieves...